# Convert dataframe to list with numeric vectors in r

Tags: r, list, numeric

I would like to transform values from a dataset to a list as numeric values.

Here is a sample dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(5.5, 6, 7),
  b = c(1.1, 2.5, 3.5))

# convert dataframe to list
df.list <- split(df, seq(nrow(df)))
```

[image]

The list looks like the above in the R environment. My desired output in the R environment is like below by getting rid of the `$`s, `a`s, and `b`s.

[image]

I tried this below but it did not really give what I wanted.

```
for (i in 1:length(df.list)) {
  df.list[[i]] <- lapply(df.list[[i]], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(df.list[[i]])))
  
}
```

[image]

Does ANyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `asplit` from `base R`.  Specify the `MARGIN` as 1 for rows and 2 for column wise split

```
out <- lapply(asplit(unname(df), 1), as.vector)
str(out)
#List of 3
#$ : num [1:2] 5.5 1.1
#$ : num [1:2] 6 2.5
#$ : num [1:2] 7 3.5
```

---

Or another option is `apply`

```
out2 <- do.call(c, apply(unname(df), 1, list)) 
identical(out, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

From the OP's `split`, we can `unlist` the list elements

```
out3 <- lapply(unname(df.list), unlist, use.names = FALSE)
identical(out, out3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: appreciated your quick turnaround. Great solutions. I picked the first one.